# Google PubSub with Dataflow using Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-cloud, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Developing a realtime tracking system using `Spring framework` and `Google Cloud Platform`.
`Spring Cloud GCP` enables to easily write a `GCP PubSub` application `Spring Integration` way. From their github page i was able to write the following application like: [Github Samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp)

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class GCPConfiguration {
    /*
    *   Message sender code
    * */
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubSubOutputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubsubTemplate) {
        PubSubMessageHandler adapter =
                new PubSubMessageHandler(pubsubTemplate, "exampleTopic");
        adapter.setPublishCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                log.info("There was an error sending the message.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                log.info("Message was sent successfully.");
            }
        });

        return adapter;
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubSubOutputChannel")
    public interface PubSubOutboundGateway {
        void sendToPubSub(String text);
    }

    /*
    *   Message receiver code
    * */
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("pubsubInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubOperations pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, "exampleSubscription");
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel")
    public void messageReceiver(String payload, @Header(GcpHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGEMENT) AckReplyConsumer ackReplyConsumer) {
        log.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + payload);

        ackReplyConsumer.ack();
    }
}
```

Tracking devices will continuously be sending data to a `TCP` port exposed by this application which needs to be transformed then persisted to `BigQuery` and `GC SQL`. Getting data from `TCP` port and publishing it to `GC PubSub` is already in place.
What i don't know is how and where to add `Google Cloud Dataflow` code that is coming from `GC PubSub`

### Update

The goal is to insert data to `GC BigQuery` and `GC SQL`, so answer that will lead to data inserted in those services is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your question is how to use Google Cloud Dataflow to stream from Pub/Sub to Bigquery.

The Dataflow site links to this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master-1.x/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/StreamingWordExtract.java) from its examples [page](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/all-examples). Note that this is using version 1.x of the SDK and not the 2.x Apache Beam version. You can find a similar example [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/3161904d97e9eb4ec6eb354fb54d8d0e4e5733eb/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/StreamingWordExtract.java).

There is also a Google-provided [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates) that can be used and requires no coding.

Edit: the template was recently open-sourced and is available on [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java).